# Creating Java Class that can contain one variable of any type

Tags: java, class, object, processing

I'm making a scene class for which I'd like a *not yet defined* variable type.

```
class Scene {
 int fps = 60;
 float duration;
 // one instance of any variable type (another class)
}
```

as sometimes I'd like the scene to be constructed using :

```
class Scene {
 int fps = 60;
 float duration;
 Simulation1 simulation;
}
```

and other times I'd like the scene to be constructed using

```
class Scene {
 int fps = 60;
 float duration;
 Simulation2 simulation;
}
```

**Simulation1** and **Simulation2** are both two very different custom classes but they have some function names in common. For example they both have functions called init(), deleteRandomParticles() and more. Which means that in my main code I can call  :

```
scene.simulation.init();
scene.simulation.deleteRandomParticles();
```

I find this very practical, but I can't find a way to make the scene class work this way.

full solution :

```
class Scene<T extends SceneInterface> {
 T simulation;

 Scene(T simulation) { 
  this.simulation = simulation; 
 }   
}

interface SceneInterface {
 public void init();
 public void deleteRandomParticles();
}
```

and make sure to have this in your simulation classes :

```
class Simulation1 implements SceneInterface{
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 1: `Object`.

```
class Scene {
 int fps = 60;
 float duration;
 Object simulation;
}
```

Option 2: A `Simulation` interface that `Simulation1` and `Simulation2` both implement.

```
class Scene {
 int fps = 60;
 float duration;
 ISimulation simulation;
}
```

Option 3: A generic type `T`

```
class Scene<T> {
 int fps = 60;
 float duration;
 T simulation;
}
```

Comment: are there any more required inside the constructor ? I've edited my question to include it as I'm still hitting a wall. could it be that Processing doesn't include these particularities ? I don't find any mention of them on the processing forums

Comment: If you use `Object`, then your callers will have to check if the `simulation` is a `Simulation1` or a `Simulation2` or a `SimulationN` using `instance of` then cast to the appropriate class before you can invoke your instances. Use a common interface (option 2), or a generic type (option 3).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're looking for generics, which is the thing that goes in the angular brackets in something like `List<String>`. Also, if your simulation classes have methods in common I would make a simulation interface and have simulation 1 and 2 implement it. You can make generics extend an interface like this: `class Scene<T extends Simulation>`
Then use type T as if it were a variable type like String.